# Does POSIX specify whether to continue script when nested dot fails?

Tags: posix

For example, if I have `example.sh` with following content

```bsh
. non-existing.sh
echo 'continues!'
```

Then I source the script in an interactive session with `. ./example.sh`, should I see “continues!” in the terminal? The [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) specifies

> If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be considered a syntax error.

I understand that if I `. non-existing.sh` the session should continues, but I’m not sure how it applies to nested sources. In Bash it continues running after printing the error message (even with `set -o posix`); in Dash it aborts current script (`example.sh`). I wonder whether this is Bash not compliant to POSIX, or is this unspecified (implementation-defined behavior) in POSIX?

Comment: Please explain what you actually mean by "nested sources"?   Do you mean a shell script which sources another shell script which in turn sources third shell script, and so on?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the example above, I sourced `example.sh`, which sourced `non-existing.sh`, so this is two-level nested.

Comment: @rowboat Then maybe it’s Dash not POSIX-compliant, always treating sourced script as non-interactive?

Comment: With this special "feature", `bash` is non-POSIX compliant. This has recently been discussed in the POSIX teleconference.

Comment: @schily, are there any notes on that online? Just if someone would like to make a bug report

Comment: IIRC, this was discussed with https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1384 but the long discussion is at posix.rhansen.org, you would need to search on your own.

Comment: Have you tried POSIX-compliant command `set -e` at first?

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear I know what `set -e` means, but it’s not required for switching to POSIX mode. I specifically don’t want `errexit` in this script. POSIX behavior should have been well-defined, with or without `set -e`.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX is silent about nested sourced files, but I suspect that, if an interpretation request were raised, the existing text for `dot` would apply.

From [IEEE Std 1003.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot):

> ***NAME***
>
> dot - execute commands in the current environment
>
> ***SYNOPSIS***
>
> `. file`
>
> ***DESCRIPTION***
>
> The shell shall execute commands from the *file* in the current environment.
>
> If *file* does not contain a <slash>, the shell shall use the search path specified by *PATH* to find the directory containing *file*. Unlike normal command search, however, the file searched for by the *dot* utility need not be executable. If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be considered a syntax error.

As regards `dash` or `bash`, there is no requirement on either shell unless they claim to to be fully conformant to IEEE Std 1003.1-2017.

Interestingly, [the current `dash(1)` manpage on Debian Stretch](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dash/dash.1.en.html)
contains the following text:

> **dash** is the standard command interpreter for the system. 
> The current version of **dash** is in the process of being changed
> to conform with the POSIX 1003.2 and 1003.2a specifications for the shell. 
> ... Only features designated by POSIX, plus a few Berkeley extensions,
> are being incorporated into this shell.

All this manpage says about **`.`** is:

> `. file`
>
> The commands in the specified file are read and executed by the shell.

As you see, `dash` makes no claim to conform to IEEE Std 1003.1-2017.  Notwithstanding this, I postulate that the `dash` behavior is probably "wrong" from a standards viewpoint in that it aborts the current script rather than continuing.

Comment: I have found this document, and mentioned it in the question. I feel like this section didn’t explain the different behavior for Bash and Dash mentioned in the question. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: In its [home page](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/), Dash claims to be POSIX compliant

Comment: @Quasímodo. But it's manpage says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort
>
> …
>
> Otherwise, [if non-interactive] return the value of the last command executed — https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot

The 2nd quoted line suggests that the exit code of earlier commands is ignored. However I hope that if you put the shell in exit-on-error mode. Then that is what it should do.

Comment: If we take the example in the question, did you mean that the exit code of `. non-existing.sh` should be ignored, and the shell should move forward to the echo statement?

Comment: It was a long time since looking at this question. But I have just read again. I seem to be saying that the manual says that it (the default behaviour) depends on if the shell is interactive or not.